# How to trigger build on multiple servers

Tags: jenkins

I have written a pipeline script using stages, using each stage to deploy code to each server from my nexus.

If I grow to 100 servers, I can not write such a number of stages. So need to minimize to single stage and to deploy the code on all servers at a time. Can anyone help me to get into the right direction?